# Spring - How to get app to read environment variable from properties file

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-config

I have several Spring based apps - web, web services

For my web services project, in my ws-config.xml file, I specify the location of the wsdl. This has been set to localhost in the past, but I now need to have this as a configurable value in a properties file if I can.

```
<ws:dynamic-wsdl id="ServiceDefinition"
    portTypeName="Test" locationUri="http://localhost/Test/webservice">
    <ws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/my-test.xsd" />
</ws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

I need to be able to reference the locationUri as a property, but I dont know how to do it?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). You can use this to specify properties in your Spring configs, and specify which properties sources to populate this property from. You can specify a hierarchy of sources, such that (say) you have a file of default properties, and then some overridden values in a per-user config.

Here's a [trivial example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/).